# Display different forms according to MYSQL values

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am very new to MYSQL and PHP and developing a sample Course registration application in xampp. This Mobile app takes data from user and inserts data in MYSQL.

My SQL table contains user details which are collected while registration.

```
id | name | Gender
------------------
1  | n1   | male
2  | n2   | female
3  | n3   | male
4  | n4   | female
```

Now checking to the registered values in the table as, how to display different forms for male and different for females.

EDIT: 
My forms are made of HTML5 elements . Once the if else condition is checked with values in database, how to read the HTML5 forms accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried with simple if statements and it worked

Answer (score 1):

First you do a query to the mysql database where you fetch the data. You do not include any name of the table in your example, but if we use the example table name as "users" the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

If you only want to select the sex, and from a specific userid. You could do the following query:

```
SELECT sex FROM users WHERE id="5";
```

Now there are many different ways to execute MYSQL code in PHP. Some of them are:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)
- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Recommendations are to use PDO or mysqli since the standard mysql library have some flaws.

Anyway, you return the sex to an array with the function of the library of your choice, and then you make a if-statement to check the value of `Sex`, and then present the form you want.

Example:

```
if($row['sex'] == 'Male'){
    //Display Form for Male
}
elseif($row['sex'] == 'Female'){
    //Display Form for Female
}
```

Comment: can you refer any example / tutorial to fetch the data accordingly

Comment: It depends what kind of library you want to use. Click on the links that I linked to in the answer and there you will find a lot of documentation and information about how to use each of them.